How to Retrieve and Display Nonsequential Records from a Large Dataset Beyond 10k Limit Without Pagination
I am currently looking into swapping over API endpoints to use elastic search since we have various search features that would benefit from an elastic search cluster. The issue I am running into is that we are currently allowing our dataset to be returned in row counts of 20 with an incremental offset. Can I replicate this in elastic search over the 10k max limit? The issue is that this dataset sometimes could be requested nonsequentially, meaning that the search_after or scroll API may not work since there is no previous search result.
I am running out of ideas and thinking that an elastic search may not be the solution, and sticking with our existing RDBMS. Do you have any thoughts/recommendations?
The main reason for this swap is that our RDBMS is constantly getting hit, and our dataset is very dynamic, so we need a solution that provides real-time results with flexible search features.
I've tried from/size, search_after, scroll api

10,000 is not a hard limit. Different indices might have varying amounts and types of data, so this limit was selected conservatively to prevent new users from having bad time by paging too far. It also serves as a reminder to consider using other more optimal mechanisms, such as search_after and the scroll API, if applicable. Switching to these mechanisms will require UI changes, and typically these changes produce better results for users. For instance, search_after will be much faster than from/size with a large from value and will consume significantly fewer resources. Moreover, when users feel compelled to page through 500 pages, it is a very strong smell of a poorly designed search interface that doesn't allow users to efficiently filter data.
That being said, sometimes you simply have to use from+size larger than 10,000. For such cases, there is a setting called index.max_result_window that allows you to increase this limit to whatever your cluster can handle.

Is increasing the index.max_result_window to 1 million+ a valid solution though? The paging is for an api so it is likely automated tools using our data.

That would be a pretty bad API design. When you are using from/size mode, elasticsearch is stateless so when you ask for records from 900,000 to 900,020 elasticsearch needs to find 900,020 records for each shard, merge sort them, then retrieve the last 20 and give them to you. No state is preserved so when you ask for  records 900,020-900,040 elasticsearch has to repeat the same work all over again. If you have enough memory to hold sort keys + ids and CPU resources to waste on doing the same job again and again it might work. Official position is you need to fix your API design.

See the comment for this setting https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7a8a7c06289fee0f3544888498ec6852b7911e7a/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/IndexSettings.java#L122-L129

That's what I was thinking as well. increasing the record count does not seem like a scalable solution. It sounds like sticking with the existing RDBMS is the better option of the two. Do you know of any good API design architecture designs or research?

That's not what I am saying. I think changing your API is the best option. Such API is a really bad design for any DB on the backend if you want to keep your backend stateless. It's just elasticsearch gives you this feedback and warns you because it tries to keep things efficient. You can ignore this feedback and switch to another RDBMS that just does this grunt work silently, but any system would have to do the same thing unless you stash a cursor somewhere. But even with cursor in many RDBMS you have the same restrictions as with scroll api in elasticsearch.
